# Parameterized propeller - Arc length

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization, arc-length

I am dealing with the book **Differential geometry of curves and surfaces**, by  **Manfredo P. do Carmo** (see Spanish version [here](https://www.academia.edu/38949108/Geometria_diferencial_de_curvas_y_superficies_Manfredo_P._do_Carmo_Comprimido)).

The exercise number 1.a of page 36 ask:

> Given the parameterized curve (propeller)
> $$\alpha(s)=\bigg(a\cos \dfrac{s}{c}, a\sin\dfrac{s}{c},b\dfrac{s}{c}\bigg),\qquad s \in \mathbb{R},$$
> where $c^2=a^2+b^2,$
>
> a) Show that the parameter $s$ is the arc length.

Well, I know that the parametrisation is by arc length iff the tangent has norm $1$... right?

But:

$$|\alpha'(s)|^2=a^2\bigg(\cos^2\dfrac{s}{c}+\sin^2\dfrac{s}{c}\bigg)+b^2\dfrac{s^2}{c^2}=a^2+b^2\dfrac{s^2}{c^2}=a^2\bigg(1-\dfrac{s^2}{c^2}\bigg)+1.$$

I believe that is easy, but I am stucked.

Many thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like you’ve computed the norm of $\alpha$ instead of $\alpha'$.

Comment: Oh... Is it. Sorry and many thanks.